# How to find all the points having a latitude and longitude between the reference point?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, error-handling, dataframe

I was looking to extract all the points which have a longitude and latitude between a range of values I've defined ealier.
Those values are stored in dataframe:

```
Latitude = 10
Longitude = 10
Lat_min = Latitude - 0.5
Lat_max = Latitude + 0.5
Lon_min = Longitude - 0.5
Lon_max = Longitude + 0.5

Df_lat_lon = Df[(Df['Latitutedx100'] >= Lat_min) & (Df['Latitutedx100'] <= Lat_max)] 
           & Df[(Df['Longitudex100'] >= Lon_min) & (Df['Longitudex100'] <= Lon_max)]
```

It returned me a rare error that seems to have no solution yet (thus its name):

```
NotImplementedError: couldn't find matching opcode for 'and_bdd'
```

I would be like to know if anyone knows a little bit more about the "opcode" and the 'and_bdd'.

**What are they meaning?**

Note: the right way of doing the task is:

```
Df_lat_lon = Df[(Df['Latitutedx100'] >= Lat_min) & (Df['Latitutedx100'] <= Lat_max) 
              & (Df['Longitudex100'] >= Lon_min) & (Df['Longitudex100'] <= Lon_max)]
```

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4934, https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6762, https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8560?

Comment: can you show some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this instead:

```
Df_lat_lon = Df[(Df.Latitutedx100.between(Lat_min, Lat_max)) & (Df.Longitudex100.between(Lon_min, Lon_max))]
```